# How common is the word 'den' (for a room)?

Tags: word-usage

I was wondering how common the word 'den' is in English speaking countries (I'm refering to the definition like on wikipedia for a room: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Den_%28room%29)? 
Do people use it to describe a room, or is it more associated to other things, like an animal's den?
Thank you.

Comment: Yes.  That is to say, it is commonly used in both senses.  People in the real estate business would more likely use it the former sense; zoologists more likely in the latter. Which one is "more common" is not really knowable, and, in my opinion, not worth being concerned about.

Comment: @Brian I think it _is_ knowable, just it would take a lot of resources to do it.

Answer (score 1):

People will have no difficulty understanding the word "den" and the context will determine if it means a room or an animal's habitat.  Really, the former is just the loose application of the latter to humans; it's somewhere cozy to retire to for both.

The [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/den) lists the animal first, but the other meanings are shown as just sub-versions of the same meaning.

Comment: OED lists meanings in order by chronological appearance, not by frequency of use.